# Gradient addition in UITableviewCell causing animation issue on reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, calayer, cagradientlayer

I want to make chat screen, and the chat bubbles have some gradient. While applying gradient to `UIView` its creating problem in reloading.

GradientView has been setup as the class of UIView which is placed on `UITableViewCell`

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    func setup() {
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    func configure() {
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [RGBA(r: 167, g: 1, b: 88, a: 1.0).cgColor, RGBA(r: 243, g: 135, b: 32, a: 1.0).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
        configure()
    }
}
```

The problem is while reloading the table view the gradient shows up with animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many properties you set on `CALayer` and its subclasses will be animated by default. For a gradient layer, this includes the bounds, the gradient colours, and the start and end points, all of which you are setting here.

This is called implicit animation.

You can turn it off by creating a transaction, disabling actions, performing your changes, then committing the transaction:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
// Do your stuff
CATransaction.commit()
```

However, that can get a bit messy. An alternative is to create a non-animating layer subclass and use that instead of `CAGradientLayer`:

```
class NonAnimatingGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    override func action(forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        return NSNull()
    }
}
```

Use this instead of `CAGradientLayer` and nothing will be animated.

Answer (score 0):

`layoutSubviews` is called many times

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    var gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer!

    func setup() {

        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [RGBA(r: 167, g: 1, b: 88, a: 1.0).cgColor, RGBA(r: 243, g: 135, b: 32, a: 1.0).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews() 
        if gradientLayer == nil {
            setup()
        }
    }

}
```